# Is there any use-case for glMapNamedBuffer instead of glGetNamedBufferSubData or glNamedBufferSubData

Tags: c++, opengl

I know that the following is UB in c++ due how the standard defines lifetime, and how objects are allowed to be used:

```
Foo* foo = std::reinterpret_cast<Foo *>(malloc(sizeof(struct Foo)));
// read or write to foo
```

So to my understanding, the following would also be UB:

```
Foo * foo = std::reinterpret_cast<Foo *>(glMapNamedBuffer(/*...*/));
// read or write to foo
```

(`Foo` is a trivial copy and constructable object)

Based on that the pointer I get from `glMapNamedBuffer` can only be used in combination with `std::memcpy` to copy data from or into the memory block that pointer is addressing, but if this is the case isn't `glMapNamedBuffer` kinda useless in the context of c++, as I could use  `glGetNamedBufferSubData` and `glNamedBufferSubData` instead as I need to copy the data anyway?

Or would the following also be UB and I would need to use a `std::memcpy` in any case:

```
Foo foo;
glNamedBufferSubData( 1, 0, sizeof(Foo), &foo);
```

```
Foo foo;
glGetNamedBufferSubData( 2, 0, sizeof(Foo), &foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to forget for the moment the fact that, as someone using a low-level API, you shouldn't be caring about undefined behavior of this sort, since this is pretty much what low-level programming is. So instead, we're in a world where we've decided that the only thing which matters is what the C++ standard actually says.

Given that:

> So to my understanding, the following would also be UB:

Well, that rather depends: what is in that memory? Did you put an object there? Is the object you put there a `Foo`? If you didn't put a `Foo` there, you can put one there easily enough:

```
void *mem_ptr = glMapNamedBuffer(/*...*/);
Foo *ptr = new(mem_ptr) Foo;
```

Now there's a `Foo` there and we have a pointer to it. What's the problem? You can treat mapping a buffer as a fancy `malloc`.

Your next thought might be, but wait, what happens when I unmap the memory and map it again? Does OpenGL ensure that I'm getting a pointer to the same object? Could it be mapped to different addresses and break the C++ object model?

Again, given that we've decided to care about things that don't actually matter, OpenGL is entirely ignorant of the C++ object model. It's just looking at bytes of storage; that's all OpenGL preserves. Any particular mapping operation will only preserve the bytes, not the C++ objects around them (which are bound to memory addresses).

But we don't have to care about that if we [persistently map buffers](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object#Persistent_mapping) (which is the only way you should map buffers, given that you're clearly using APIs that *require* persistent mapped buffers to be available). There, you just map the pointer and you're done. You can do whatever you need with it.

And if you're reading data, you generally want that data out of the buffer object's memory ASAP. Reading from memory that is genuinely mapped to GPU memory can be exceedingly slow, so just doing a `memcpy` into an existing object would be appropriate. And with persistent mapped buffers, reading can be done after checking your fence to see if the data is available.

Comment: I know that I can do `Foo *ptr = new(mem_ptr) Foo;` (at least since 4.2, before that that was possibly UB due to none guaranteed alignment).

Comment: But if I map the buffer to read the data that was updated by a shader, then calling `new(mem_ptr) Foo` on each entry in the buffer does not make sense. `You can do whatever you need with it.` why should I be allowed to use `std::reinterpret_cast<Foo *>(pointer)` and work on it as if it is a pointer to an array? How should a pointer returned `glMapNamedBuffer` be different to `malloc`? There is a proposal how to allow that in c++ [P0593R4 Implicit creation of objects for low-level object manipulation](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0593r4.html) but for now it's UB.

Comment: @t.niese: You may want to look at the part of my post starting with "And if you're reading data...". "*How should a pointer returned glMapNamedBuffer be different to malloc?*" I don't really understand what you're getting at here. I even said "You can treat mapping a buffer as a fancy `malloc`."